# How to switch focus back to the editor in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want a quick way to switch between file explorer and file editor. I got a keybind to focus on file explorer, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>, but what's the default keybind for focusing on file editor, and how to do it using command palette?

I tried <kbd>esc</kbd>, which just focuses on the whole file explorer (when a file is selected).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> depending on the tab groups you have, you have key binds up to `8`

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> is: **View: Open Last Editor in Group**

for windows it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>

Comment: So just like navigating Chrome tabs. Thanks.

Comment: you get an upvote (when i get enough karma to do it)